# Merging text files based on headings.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, split

I am looking for some advice on how I could merge multiple text files based on their headings.

So say I have the following 3 text files with the following headings. As you can see some elements repeat and some are unique to the text file. The text files contain thousands of rows under each header containing various types of data.

Text File 1:

Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5|
00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005|

Text File 2:

Element2|Element3|Element4|Element5|
00000002|00000003|00000004|00000005|

Text File 3:

Element1|Element3|Element4|Element6|
00000001|00000003|00000004|00000006|

**The final output Text File would would look something like this:**

Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5|Element3|Element6|
00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005|00000003|________|
________|00000002|00000004|00000005|________|________|
00000001|________|00000004|________|00000003|00000006|

As you can see the output text file would capture every header from the original 3 Text Files. It would then store each data field under the appropriate heading. If an element is not available in a particular Text File then the field is left empty.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Do you have any code that's not working properly?

Comment: I have an application built out that splits out certain elements similar to how I have it above using .split and a dictionary tuple. However I'm not sure how I can go about merging text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show us what code you already have, then ask how to approach the part that you cannot solve.

I suggest you to store a list of headers, and a list or dictionary of rows. This way you could check if a header already exists.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestElements
{
    public class Elements
    {
        public static string[] ROW_SEPARATOR = { " " };
        public static string[] ELEMENT_SEPARATOR = { "|" };

        private int _nextRowId;
        public List<string> ColumnHeaders;
        public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> Rows;

        public Elements()
        {
            this._nextRowId = 0;
            this.ColumnHeaders = new List<string>();
            this.Rows = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        public void AddFromFile(string path)
        {
            // Read all the file, and split in lines
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(ROW_SEPARATOR, StringSplitOptions.None);

            // Get the headers
            List<string> headers = lines[0].Split(ELEMENT_SEPARATOR, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

            // Add headers that are new
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                if (!this.ColumnHeaders.Contains(header))
                {
                    this.ColumnHeaders.Add(header);
                }
            }

            // Parse every line
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                // Split a line into elements
                List<string> elements = lines[i].Split(ELEMENT_SEPARATOR, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

                // Build a row of elements
                Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                for (int j = 0; j < headers.Count; j++)
                {
                    row.Add(headers[j], elements[j]);
                }

                // Add the row to our store
                this.AddRow(row);
            }
        }

        private void AddRow(Dictionary<string, string> rowdata)
        {
            this.Rows.Add(this._nextRowId, rowdata);
            this._nextRowId++;
        }
    }
}
```

Take care I'm not checking for errors in this example.

Then you can build the output text as you wants.

If you have any more concrete question, or this does not help enough, just ask.

---

EDIT: Here is an example of usage

```
        // Create a few files to use in a test
        string TextFile1 = 
            "Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5| " +
            "00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005| " +
            "00000011|00000012|00000014|00000015| " +
            "00000021|00000022|00000024|00000025| " +
            "00000031|00000032|00000034|00000035|";
        string TextFile2 =
            "Element2|Element3|Element4|Element5| " +
            "00000002|00000003|00000004|00000005| " +
            "00000012|00000013|00000014|00000015| " +
            "00000022|00000023|00000024|00000025|";
        string TextFile3 =
            "Element1|Element3|Element4|Element6| " +
            "00000001|00000003|00000004|00000006| " +
            "00000011|00000013|00000014|00000016| " +
            "00000021|00000023|00000024|00000026| " +
            "00000031|00000033|00000034|00000036| " +
            "00000041|00000042|00000044|00000045|";

        File.WriteAllText("File1.txt", TextFile1);
        File.WriteAllText("File2.txt", TextFile2);
        File.WriteAllText("File3.txt", TextFile3);

        // Read the files into our class
        Elements elements = new Elements();
        elements.AddFromFile("File1.txt");
        elements.AddFromFile("File2.txt");
        elements.AddFromFile("File3.txt");

        // Build the result
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // First build headers
        foreach (string header in elements.ColumnHeaders)
        {
            sb.Append(header);
            sb.Append("|");
        }
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        // Next add every row
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in elements.Rows.Values)
        {
            foreach (string header in elements.ColumnHeaders)
            {
                if (row.ContainsKey(header))
                {
                    sb.Append(row[header]);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append("________");
                }
                sb.Append("|");
            }
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // Finally save the result into a file
        File.WriteAllText("Result.txt", sb.ToString());
```

And the result looks like this:

```
Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5|Element3|Element6|
00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005|________|________|
00000011|00000012|00000014|00000015|________|________|
00000021|00000022|00000024|00000025|________|________|
00000031|00000032|00000034|00000035|________|________|
________|00000002|00000004|00000005|00000003|________|
________|00000012|00000014|00000015|00000013|________|
________|00000022|00000024|00000025|00000023|________|
00000001|________|00000004|________|00000003|00000006|
00000011|________|00000014|________|00000013|00000016|
00000021|________|00000024|________|00000023|00000026|
00000031|________|00000034|________|00000033|00000036|
00000041|________|00000044|________|00000042|00000045|
```

Comment: Blas - Thanks for your response! I've been trying to implement your code and its been pretty useful so far. Question: How would I call a particular header from the rowdata dictionary? Because it looks like the _nextRowId is just a count for the rows in a text file and then rowdata is all headers in the text file attached to that row count.

In other words how can I get header number 5 from row 3?

Comment: @erick That was just a suggested approach, before you added a comment about the way you are trying. I added an example of usage. If you would like guidance on your own approach, please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Blas - This has been tremendously helpful. Thanks for your effort and time.